# Keep state of multiple usercontrols in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am generating instances of a `UserControl` and putting them in an `UL`. In my `UserControl` there is a button with an event. I want to ask how I can keep the state of the UserControls I generated so that they remain on the page after a postback and also to catch their events.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To lstFoo.Count - 1     
  Dim liFoo As New HtmlGenericControl("li")
  Dim ucMyFoo As ucFoo = LoadControl("userControls/ucFoo.ascx")

  liFoo.Controls.Add(ucMyFoo)   
  ucMyFoo.DoSomething()
  ulFoo.Controls.Add(liFoo)
Next
```

Comment: You are not assigning an ID to ucMyFoo. If anything is different after the postback (e.g. the # of items in lstFoo) which results in a different control set being generated, this could be the problem.

Comment: Hmm the ID did the trick, post an answer and I'll mark it for you

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like on the post, you are not running the logic listed above.  Are you only running the above code on the GET request?  You can make sure it is executed in the Page_Load regardless of GET or POST.

Another way you can do it is by writing a UL web user control that has the logic to add the ucFoo.ascx control builtin.  Then just include this UL web user control (ascx) to your webform.

This will make your life easier, since this new web user control will always be on the page, and you're not adding the control dynamically.

Comment: When I put the code on postback , the userControl simple gets regenerated so I lose the events

Comment: tried putting the List in another usercontrol....I still lose the list of usercontrols on postback

Comment: You have to re-add the event handler as well.  It should then work as expected.  Generally it's nicer to add things in the aspx markup if you can so you can avoid these headaches.

Comment: The amount of usercontrols generated vary, so can't write in the markup.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but you might want to add the event handler before adding the UC to `liFoo`